# Ag-grid How to add a new row when using Server-side Row model and Partial row store

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I'm using Ag-grid enterprise(v25.1.0) to displaying my data. I'm using the **Server-Side Row Model (SSRM)** and the **partial store** row store type . I'm able to render the data correctly and now I want to be able to add new row. How can I add a new row?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like with partial data stores the only way to update data is to update it on the server and then refresh the data. The [docs](https://www.ag-grid.com/archive/26.2.0/react-data-grid/server-side-model-row-stores/#partial-store-restrictions) mention this as a restriction of the partial store.

If you want to update rows on the server and re-fetch the data. Here's an [example](https://www.ag-grid.com/archive/26.2.0/react-data-grid/server-side-model-updating/#update--refresh) of that.